# Safari 5 Exentsions

Tags: javascript, html, safari, safari-extension

I'm trying to teach myself Safari 5 extensions and I'm new to web development in general. Looking at the sample code, I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script>
...
</script>
```

I'm just wondering, what language am I looking at? I see functions and code that almost looks C-like. Apple's documentation says it would be helpful to know HTML, javascript, CSS, and HTMl5 but I'm not sure what their samples are written in.

Answer (score 1):

`...` is used in code examples as a placeholder, to say "insert more code here" - perhaps this is where you are confused? If you point us to the sample you are referring to, that may help to clarify.

If anything else looks unfamiliar - it may be "The Safari Extensions JavaScript API" which may contain some possibly unfamiliar looking JavaScript - from having a quick nose around - there doesn't seem to be any other technologies present.

`<script>` tags are used to allow inline javascript inside a HTML page - generally - [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp) is a good stop for concise explanations of HTML tags. `<script>` opens up the area in the page that will be interpreted as javascript code by the browser, while `</script>` signifies it has ended.

So the `...` in this case is simply an indicator of where your custom JavaScript code should be.

The `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` is a [HTML 5 doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp) - 'an instruction to the web browser about what version of the markup language the page is written in'

Comment: Ah my bad. I didn't realize Stack Overflow tried to interpret the code I pasted. I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: @Travis - No worries - amended answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, it's definitely mixed HTML5 and javascript.